# using sudoers to allow non-privileged user to restart apache

Tags: centos, security, sudo, apache-httpd

We have production centos servers that run apache as root to allow low port numbers (80 and 443).

We'd like a secure way for non-root users to restart apache.

Are there any security implications with adding something like this to the sudoers file...

```
username    ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/service apache2 reload
```

Specifically I'd like to know if there is any way for the user to then elevate their privileges, or somehow run other programs as root.

Comment: [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45712/how-secure-is-nopasswd-in-passwordless-sudo-mode) might help you.

Comment: link is already provided

Comment: @Rahul This is useful. However it seems to be mostly discussing the implications of NOPASSWD sudo access generally. What I want to do is use it from a release script, where entering a password is impossible. The user already has ssh access to the machine, but doesn't have any sudo access currently. I'm just wondering if sudo access to a specific executable can be exploited to provide any higher level access.

Comment: AFAIK No it doesn't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let´s say you want to allow users bellonging to the group users2 to do some privileged control over `apache` without giving them root privilege.

Add to `/etc/sudoers`

```
%users2 keep ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/service httpd,/etc/init.d/httpd,/usr/sbin/apache2ctl
```

If you just want them to restart `apache` it will be:

```
%users2 ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/service httpd restart,/etc/init.d/httpd restart,/usr/sbin/apache2ctl restart
```

The users will be able to see what commands they are allowed to use with `sudo` with:

```
sudo -l
```

And to restart Apache they have to spell out exactly the command as they are allowed to run it, for instance:

```
sudo /sbin/service httpd restart
```

It is advisable to define the full path of commands in the sudoers file, for security reasons.

Comment: This is tagged as 'centos' so the service name should be 'httpd' not 'apache2'.

Comment: Does the command need to match exactly? For example, is it able to recognize that "$ service http restart" is the same as "$ /sbin/service http restart"? More importantly, will it block sudo access to ~/bin/service, if that's in the users path?

Comment: It needs to match exactly, and it is better that way for security reasons. Otherwise your user could run a script with the same name to escalate to root, as you seem to have already figured out. If the user does not remember the correct path, teach them about `sudo -L`

Comment: On Ubuntu, /sbin/service does not work but /etc/init.d/ works like a charm.

Comment: @Josir  /etc/init.d or systemctl for systemd. Do not have my Debian at hand today, will confirm tomorrow.

Comment: This command could fail if apache2/httpd have to read a directory which isn't readable by given user. This is the case, e.g. for setting up letsencrypt: Then restarting failed, because apache want also read `/etc/letsencrypt/live/...` for example.

Comment: @colidyre Being apache2/httpd invoked with sudo, Apache is not launched using the   original non-privileged user id/gid.